# event.target jquery on() mousedown/up is not giving the dom specified by selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, event-bubbling

I have this simple html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <span class="higher">
        [higher]
        <span class="lower">
            hello
        </span>
    </span>
</div>​
```

and this js:

```
$('.wrapper').on('mousedown', '.higher', function(e){
    alert($(e.target).attr('class'))
    })​
```

Basically, when I click on the "hello" word, I am getting the "lower" instead of "higher". How can I make it so that the event's target is the same as specified in the selector parameter of the `on()`?

Here's a little fiddle for this
http://jsfiddle.net/TUvB7/2/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `this` instead, `e` is the element that started the bubbling

```
$('.wrapper').on('mousedown', '.higher', function(e){
    alert($(this).attr('class')) // Changed line
})​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TUvB7/7/

Answer (score 1):

why need `e.target`?

```
$('.wrapper').on('mousedown', '.higher', function(e){
    alert($(this).attr('class'))
})​
```